# Process of Arecoline Extraction

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry, esters, chemical-engineering, alkaloids

What would be the proper procedure to extract and isolate arecoline, an alkaloid ester, from the seed of the Areca nut, and is it possible to mass produce arecoline using that method?

Comment: Go to Google. Type "arecoline extraction". You will find at least $5$ references about how to do this extraction. But it seems difficult, because it needs a cation exchange resin, then membrane ultrafiltration, freeze dehydration and distillation under high pressure.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the brief description of arecoline given by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arecoline):

> Arecoline is a base, and its conjugate acid has a $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ ~6.8. Arecoline is volatile in steam, miscible with most organic solvents and water, but extractable from water by ether in presence of dissolved salts. Being basic, arecoline forms salts with acids. The salts are crystalline, but usually deliquescent: the hydrochloride, arecoline•HCl, forms needles, m.p. $\pu{158 ^\circ C}$; and the hydrobromide, arecoline•HBr, forms slender prisms, mp. $177$–$\pu{179 ^\circ C}$ from hot alcohol.

Thus, you can use several different methods to isolate it from bio matrices if you have some experience in natural product chemistry. My best bet would have been the technique called steam distillation since it'd be the cheapest method to do so (Ref.1; recovery of arecoline was highest, about 96%, in the distillation method compared to other methods used). A typical procedure can be outlined as follows:

> Place $\pu{2.5 g}$ 30-mesh powdered sample of arecoline nut in distillation flask. Add $\pu{5 mL}$ $\pu{0.3 N}$ $\ce{NaOH}$ solution and wet sample uniformly. Place receiver containing $\pu{10 mL}$ $\pu{0.02 N}$ $\ce{H2SO4}$ in ice bath, with stem of condenser dipping in acid. Connect apparatus and let steam bubble through material. Adjust heating so that first drop of distillate drips into receiver 2-3 min after entry of steam. Collect $\pu{150 mL}$ or more of distillate in $\pu{15 min}$. Conduct blank distillation with the reagents without sample. Titrate distillate against standard $\pu{0.022 N}$ $\ce{NaOH}$, using methyl red as indicator. From difference in titer values, deduce arecoline content. $\pu{1 mL}$ $\pu{0.02 N}$ $\ce{NaOH}$ is equivalent to $\pu{0.003108 g}$ arecoline.

The following facts are important in this distillation:

> The arecoline nuts should be powdered (mesh size of 30) and then put in a alkali solution with $\mathrm{pH}$ 0f 9.0-9.1. The conditions studied for the recovery of
> arecoline from areca nut in Ref.1 has showed that sodium carbonate and bicarbonate did not release the arecoline from the powdered nut. Sodium hydroxide of sufficient concentration was, however, highly effective for this purpose, as shown by data. Thus it can be seen from the data in Ref.1 that a value of 0.392% for arecoline was obtained for a 20-mesh powder, compared to 0.512% for a 30-mesh powder with the same quantity of alkali. Studies on the effect of distillation rate (Ref.1) has indicated that a rate of $\pu{10 mL min-1}$ and a distillate volume of $\pu{150 mL}$ were optimum for maximum recovery of arecoline from areca nut.

---

**References:**

1. E. Sankaran Nambudiri, "Estimation of Arecoline: A Rapid Distillation Method," *Journal of Association of Official Analytical Chemists* **1968**, *51(4)*, 799–802 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1093/jaoac/51.4.799).